# Submit a Form without redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

I want to submit a form without redirecting page. Form is submitted to third party so i can't make changes in php.
What I want to do is:-

1. Submit for without visiting third party page.
2. After successful submit show alert.

Current I am using hidden iframe and form target to hidden iframe but I am not satisfied. Is there is any better way to do this using javascript or jquery.

My Form:-

```
<form target="iframe" action="http://www.example.com"  type="post" id="myform">
<input type="text" value="" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

My Iframe:-

```
<iframe style="display:none" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: If the things you need to do, or show are client-side only, you could use Javascript, if you do need some server-side action, you will need a postback.

Comment: Consider submitting your form with asyncronous JavaScript and XML:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form

Comment: XHR my friend, AKA Ajax

Comment: Can you give me some codes please.

Comment: I have a doubt.. Where is method attribute for this form? Is it a valid?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to write it. I have edited the code.

Comment: why not set up a simple php script on your server to act like a proxy?

Comment: @Hayko I am beginner. Can you tell me in details

Comment: @user3141688 I've added an answer, try it out and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Ajax for that kind of request.

Please look at some tutorials, this for example http://www.w3bees.com/2013/08/submit-form-without-page-refresh-with.html

Comment: I am submitting form to third party. I can't make change in php.

Comment: Still you can manage that. http://isometriks.com/jquery-ajax-form-submission-with-iframes

Answer (score 1):

Change the iframes `id` attribute to `name`:

```
<iframe style="display:none" name="iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: the code I have written there are working correctly. I want to know is there is any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery here

```
 <form  action="http://www.example.com" id="myform">
 <input type="text" value="" name="name">
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
```

and after in jquery you write like

```
   // bind to the form's submit event 
    $('#myform').submit(function() { 
     alert("ok");
     return true; 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a PHP proxy.

Copy the script from [here](https://github.com/eslachance/php-transparent-proxy) to anywhere you like on your own server.

Modify line 11 so that it points to the URL you are posting to at the moment.
`// Destination URL: Where this proxy leads to.`
`$destinationURL = 'http://www.otherdomain.com/backend.php';`

Then in your ajax script, change the URL to your `proxy.php` script.